# Just CANNOT install MySQL with Homebrew -- postinstall won't install

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I am trying to install MySQL on my Mac running 10.9. I installed Homebrew just fine, did brew update and brew doctor, and everything came out fine. I tried "brew install mysql," and the postinstall refuses to run. Checking at Homebrew and searching here on Stack Overflow didn't find anything.

The exact ending text was:

```
014-10-11 16:28:53 1532 [ERROR] Aborting
```

2014-10-11 16:28:53 1532 [Note] Binlog end
2014-10-11 16:28:53 1532 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mysql`

I  tried to run "brew postinstall mysql," and it responded with:

```
READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

These open issues may also help:
Packages with --with-mysql option not satisfied by mariadb (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32973)
myname-macbook-pro:/ myname$

I've checked the github link, and I couldn't find any solutions. Anyone have any suggestions for the postinstall?

Comment: why are you trying to install mysql with homebrew?? I found it causes issues and the best way to do it is by going to the oracle website and download from there (homebrew install 3 times has caused me issues with working on my computer / system but if you just download it off of oracle there aren't any issues)

Comment: Because I DID try that. I downloaded the Mac OSX zip file from Oracle and tried to install the package. Just as it was seeming to finish up, the installer threw up a vague "An error occurred in installing. Please contact the software vendor." Didn't say anything about exact nature of the error, didn't point me to a troubleshooting page, log, or anything.

Comment: did you ensure that all of the specs were correct? like the version you downloaded?

Comment: Yes. I got the file for Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive. I have a 64-bit MacBook Pro with 10.9.5. I have Xcode and Command Line Tools installed too.

Comment: sounds like you should contact oracle and see what they say... if it threw an error there then you most likely wont be able to install it till you figure out what the error is

Comment: The mysql post-install script runs mysql_install_db unless /usr/local/var/mysql/mysql/user.frm exists. Do you already have a mysql installed somewhere on your system? What does `which mysql` say after running `brew unlink mysql`? Please feel free to open an issue on the Homebrew tracker at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues.

Comment: I now have MySQL installed with homebrew with no errors in install, but I keep getting the Error 2002 or the following: /usr/local/bin/mysql.server: line 276: cd: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory.

Comment: You have a MySQL configuration file somewhere, probably called my.cnf, that is instructing MySQL to look in the wrong place. If you search out and remove stray configuration files, that should help.

Comment: I tried the MySQL install route again, and it still won't install. I don't have any my.conf files anywhere on my machine, either. This is an excerpt from the error log file, which I already forwarded to Oracle as a bug report.

Comment: ` PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7f8a737ce410 {NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg#mysql-startup-item.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.mysql.startupitem, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg”.}

Comment: In the end, frustrated with MySQL, and seeing that even major organizations such as Wikipedia have dropped it, I finally uninstalled broken MySQL packages from my Mac. The issue seemed to be permissions and even though I'm the sole user of my computer, I didn't have root privileges. I set myself as root user and decided to try the open source MySQL "fork" known as MariaDB. And not only that, I was able to do so successfully with Homebrew. Also added and got PHPMyAdmin working. Finally have my development environment on Mac Mavericks.